# Is there a way to Pre-render a React Native Component to speed up loading?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-component

I have a Modal Component that takes 3 to 5 seconds to load.  That is simply too slow for what I want while in the middle of app usage.
Is there any way to pre-render that component when the app loads so while in the middle of usage it will simply pop up almost instantaneously?
So it is pre-rendered but not visible to the screen yet....

I am using Modal from react-native....

If not, then are there other ways to fix a slow loading component in React Native?

I'm doing this heavy calculation...
The data source is:

```
const longitudeSource = [
  R.range(-180, 181),
  R.range(0, 60),
  R.range(0, 60)
]
```

Then with the above data I input that data to `dataSources` below

```
{
                this.props.dataSources.map((source, index) => {

                  console.log('map of sources', source)
                  return <ScrollPicker
                          ref={(sp) => {this.sp = sp}}
                          dataSource={source}
                          selectedIndex={5}
                          itemHeight={50}
                          wrapperHeight={250}
                  wrapperColor={'#ffffff'}
                          highlightColor={'#d8d8d8'}
                          renderItem={(data, index, isSelected) => {
                              return(
                                  <View>
                                      <Text >{data}</Text>
                                  </View>
                              )
                          }}
                          onValueChange={(data, selectedIndex) => {
                              //
                          }}
                      />
                })
              }
```

Comment: Can you just keep it open but set `style={props.open ? {}: {display: 'none'}}`

Comment: My assumption is that the reason it takes *3-5 secs* is because of an async request. If correct, Fire request on page load and keep data in memory. On necessary action, show modal

Comment: make sure your whole component doesn't rerender on model open and close. This is a big bottleneck in performance renderering. Also test it in release build . you can use React.memo() and useCallback hook or Purecomponent in class components for preventing unnecessary renders

Comment: @HarishJangra I understand React.memo but how does useCallback play into it?

Comment: hii! did anyone have the correct answer to this problem when you are not loading the data from any API but still the loading of component takes time??? I am in dire need of the solution